# SailsJS issues with select, sort inside populate

Tags: sails.js

I wants to retrieve last 2 customer invoices with selected fields, but select, sort are not working with populate, is any way to solve this problem without using Model.query.

```
Customer.find({customer_type: 'full'})
        .populate('invoices', {
             invoice_type: 'monthly',
             select: ['id', 'customer_id', 'discount', 'total'],
             sort:{invoice_date: 'desc'}
             limit: 2
        }).exec(function(err, custumers){ //-------- });
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update.** In new Waterline v0.12 you can use select for populate method ([Waterline 0.12 changelog](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/releases/tag/v0.12.0))

<strike>In current Waterline v.0.11 you can solve this problem only with Model.query().</strike>